# How to run an installed command from any directory?

Tags: cmd

I have installed a program using (where the `.` represents which directory the executable is in).

```
\c:.> program.exe
```

Now every time I run an associated command it requires an additional backslash:

```
\c:.> \program help
```

My question is, how do I run the `\program` cmdlet from any directory and thus avoid the usage of the leading backslash?

I have considered adding the directory to my PATH variables but it looks like I'm supposed to solve this problem from within the code that runs every time that `\program` issues a command.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are saying. a) `.` is not a valid directory name. b) `\c:.>` doesn't make any sense to me (not even as a prompt) c) `\program` tells the parser to execute `program.exe` from the root of the current drive (did you really install something at `C:\`?). Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only add the path of your command to your PATH var to do what you wanna do.